# Firebase Cloud Functions: can i start a live audio stream in a firebase cloud function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

i need to know if i can start a live audio stream through firebase cloud functions. For example i upload an audio file to firebase storage and use a cloud function to start a live stream of that audio file...i have never used cloud functions before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Functions does not support streaming at all.  The entire request and response are sent in one chunk, and each are limited to 10MB in size.  You might want to read the [documentation on its limitations](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#resource_limits).